# License Key Finder on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, license-key

Are there any license key finders on Mac?

Comment: Apparently no .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, license keys are not stored as plaintext in most application preferences. They would mostly use some sort of stored hash one-way encryption.

I use [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password) to save my license keys. It's also ideal for saving passwords, naturally, and other numbers you might want to keep safe and easily accessible like credit card numbers, etc.

Another dedicated application for this purpose is [AppShelf](http://www.kedisoft.com/appshelf/).

Comment: I actually use both but I was just lookin for one of the programs that recover licenses.

Comment: 1Password FTW. Much easier to store the information as you get it instead of having to fish for it later.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I mean: license key finders for what? OS X? No. OS X doesn't have a license Key.

Comment: A software that scans through the OS to recover lost/forgotten license keys of apps installed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any software that does stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X I usually just search my e-mail for the app name and “license”. Obviously that only works if you get license keys via e-mail, and keep them.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm answering to 3 years old thread, but program you're looking for is called "Mac Product Key Finder", which can be downloaded from here:

http://mac-product-key-finder.com/

It's Freeware and works on OSX >= 10.5, but it support only 69 programs (out of millions)